# Classic ASP - Use Ajax to submit enquiry form without refresh

Tags: ajax, asp-classic, cdo.message

I've had a look through Google etc but can't find anything for what I'm after so asking my fellow SE members for a little help.

I have a form which is contained on my page and is consistent throughout the site. I would like to submit the enquiry form without the page refreshing which is the normal route with Classic ASP.

I have a separate ASP page that contains my mail script and that works fine and sends the email, however I would like to use Ajax to call that page, send the email and then inform the user that its been sent.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Classic ASP, ASP.NET, PHP or any other dynamc language, its all the same as what you're really doing is **FORM POST** ing, and that's HTML, not actually ASP.

Assuming that you have a form like

```
<form id="frm-submit" action="/SendEmail.asp" action="POST">

   ...

   <input type="submit" value="Submit form" />
</form>
```

add a little jQuery to the page as

```
$(function() {

   $("#frm-send").submit(function() {
      var data = $(this).serialize(),
          action = $(this).attr("action"),
          method = $(this).attr("method");

      $(".loading").show(); // show loading div
      $.ajax({
         url: action,
         type: method,
         data: data,
         success: function(data) {
             // all went well...
         },
         error: function(err) {
             // there was something not right...
         },
         complete: function() {
            $(".loading").hide(); // hide the loading
         }
      });

      return false; // don't let the form be submitted
   });

});
```

and you're ready to go.

---

in your `sendMail.asp` page, everything you send to `Response.Write` will be in the `data` variable of the `success` method, so after you send the email you have:

```
Response.Write("done")
Responde.Flush()
Response.End()
```

in the javascript part, you can handle it like:

```
success(data) {
    if(data === "done")
    {
       // Super duper! let's show the user a Thank you for submit page
       document.location = "/ThankYou.asp";
    }
}
```

Comment: Your JQuery is perfect, thank you. However the "success" part redirects which I get why you have done that, but is there a way of replacing the contact form with another message?  Such as "Thank you for your enquiry, we will be in contact soon"?

Comment: I have figured it out.  I placed this in the jQuery:  $('#form-contact-sidebar').hide();
       $('#submit-result').show();